# How to pass a string type for MapRoute?

Tags: string, asp.net-mvc-3, maproute, routelink

Can you guys please check this MapRoute,

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Topic", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{letter}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Topic", action = "Letter", letter = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

I'm passing an object named "letter". This is a string.
The problem that I encountered here is this, when I pass it using the .RouteLink() function

```
@Html.RouteLink(item, "Topic", new { controller = "Topic", action = "Letter", letter = "A" })
```

The result is null, for letter.

```
public ActionResult Letter(string letter)
{
return View();
}
```

Is there a way wherein I will pass a string type on the MapRoute ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Topic",                                           // Route name
            "Topic/{entry}",                                  // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Topic", action = "Letter" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```